# The use of "and" to join sentences

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, relative-clauses

The conjunction and/but is used to join two independent sentences of the same subject/s but different tenses and voices. The latter half is often shorter than the former which is more complete.

I would like to learn how to use "and" to join sentences, making them short, compact and free of repetition. What we can omit and what we can't.

Comment: Usually you may safely dispense with repeated prepositions and infinitive markers. "I'd like to learn how to use and (to) make sentences short...", (although I'm not sure what you mean by *using sentences* in this context, so I'd nix that part entirely); "He is good at math and (at) English." However, you can also keep them when clauses/phrases are longer. Sometimes being explicit is better, but it all depends on the context. I wouldn't worry about that too much, however.

Comment: If the two sentences are two different tenses, should I keep the auxiliary verb of the next sentence after "and"?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: In the Last month, I was very ill, but now completely cured.

Comment: Where do find the usage of the words and phrases, like that of, do, one and so, which are used to avoid repetition? Please suggest me a link.

Answer (score 0):

Independent clauses are basically two sentences that could stand on their own- better said, they don't "depend" on another clause to allow them to make sense."And" means also or in addition. Instead of saying, "John went to the store. Andy went to the store, too," try saying, "John and Andy went to the store."